# how to get least upper bound of two multisets

Tags: list, prolog

I need to implement a predicate:

```
leastUpper(L1,L2,L)
```

it will be satisfied when L is the least upper bound of the multisets L1 and L2. That means for each element X/N in L, X is an atom that occurs in at least one of the sets L1 and L2, and N is the largest indices of X in L1 and L2. If X does not occur in one set, then its index in that set is 0.

For example:

```
leastUpper([],[a/1,b/2,c/3],L) will be satisfied when L=[a/1,b/2,c/3]

or leastupper([a/2,b/3,c/2],[b/3,c/4,d/1],L) is satisfied if L=[a/2,b/3,c/4,d/1].
```

My current thought is like: For each element X/N in L1, check if the element X/_ exists in L2. If exists, compare their indices to get the largest index Nx, and then add X/Nx in L. At the same time, delete the corresponding elements both in L1 and L2. Continue this process till to the end of L1. For the remaining elements in L1 and L2, they only appear in one set L1 or L2, just add them in L. The raw idea could be illustrated by the following predicate:

```
check(X/N,L2) :- member(X/_,L2),compare(...),append(X/Nx,L),delete(X/_,L1,L2).
```

I don't know if my thought is correct or not and how to implement it in Prolog. Any ideas are welcome and greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're thought process is procedure rather than "Prologesque" (the logical expression of facts and inferences). For example, you want to think in terms of something like, "`L` is the `leastUpper` of `L1` and `L2` if..." but break it into pieces. One predicate might express, "`L2` is the `leastUpper` of `[]` and `L2`" so you'd have `leastUpper([], L2, L2).` Etc...

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I should take the form of thinking. But I still have no idea how to achieve the goal step by step. That's frustrating.

Comment: I gave the easy ones first. ;) For the next one, think of the logic first: "`[X/N|R] is the `leastUpper` of `[X/N1|R1]` and `L2` if `X/N2` is a member of `L2`, and `N` is maximum of `N1` and `N2`, and `R` is the `leastUpper` of R1 and L2a" where `L2a` is `L2` with `X/_` removed. Then write that in Prolog. All that's left after that is to think through the case where `X/_` is not a member of `L2`.

Comment: Thanks mbratch! Your comment is quite helpful. I have just solved this question. Best.

Comment: @user2585677 please post your own solution, I'd like to read it.

Comment: I just posted my own solution for some personal reasons. Welcome your guidance and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to agree with @mbratch. You ran right past a logical formulation to get to the procedural part. The answer I came up with is a lot simpler. The key is this sentence:

> for each element X/N in L, X is an atom that occurs in at least one of the sets L1 and L2, and N is the largest indices of X in L1 and L2.

You already have the logical definition here. Let's simplify it: an element of the least upper bound is an element X/N of the set L such that N is the largest denominator of X/N in the set. This is trivial to express in Prolog:

```
leastUpper(X/N, L) :-
    member(X/N, L),
    \+ (member(X/M, L), M > N).
```

That literally says that X/N is a least upper bound element of L if X/N is in L and there is no member X/M of L such that M is greater than N.

Notice that the least upper bound of two "multisets" is the least upper bound of two lists (the only difference between a list and a multiset is the concept of order, which isn't relevant here), and the least upper bound of two lists is the same as the least upper bound of one list (the two lists concatenated). Surprise! :) Your predicate is now two lines long:

```
leastUpper(L1, L2, L) :-
    append(L1, L2, Concatenated),
    setof(X, leastUpper(X, Concatenated), L).
```

This fulfills your requirements:

```
?- leastUpper([a/2, b/3, c/2], [b/3, c/4, d/1], L).
L = [a/2, b/3, c/4, d/1].
```

Learning how to think declaratively and logically is *by far* the hardest thing to learn about Prolog.

Some notes:

- `leastUpper/2` is a different predicate than `leastUpper/3`. Notably, the former is a generator and the latter is not. It may be wise to rename it.
- `leastUpper/2` is not especially efficient: this kind of traversal is O(N^2). You could easily replace it with a sort, followed by a linear scan, and achieve O(N log N). The replacement would probably wind up being ~5-6 lines long and maybe require another helper predicate, so if you care about this, try implementing it yourself (it isn't difficult).

Comment: Great answer, Daniel. But `Learning how to think declaratively and logically is by far the hardest thing to learn about Prolog.` misses an important point: a *big* part of every day programming doesn't fall under the declarative model. Then you need to cross the bleeding edge, and there Prolog shows its - relative - weakness

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I knew either you or CapelliC would improve upon my comment with something more succinct. :)

Comment: @CapelliC True, but every language has shortcomings, and you have to think declaratively and/or logically before Prolog can disappoint you. :)

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

```
larger(X,Y,N):- X>=Y, N=X.
larger(X,Y,N):- X<Y,N=Y.

remove([],X,[]) :- !.
remove([X|T],X,L1) :- remove(T,X,L1), !.
remove([H|T],X,[H|L1]) :- remove(T,X,L1).

check(X/N) :- atom(X), integer(N), N > 0.

least_Upper([],M2,M2):-!.
least_Upper(M1,[],M1):-!.

least_Upper([X/N1|R1],L2,[X/N|R]):-      
                  maplist(check[X/N1|R1]),maplist(check,L2),member(X/N2,L2), 
          larger(N1,N2,N), remove(L2, X/N2, L2R), least_Upper(R1,L2R,R),!.

least_Upper([X/N1|R1],L2,[X/N|R]):- maplist(check,[X/N1|R1]),maplist(check,L2),
                  \+member(X/_,L2), N=N1, least_Upper(R1,L2,R),!.
```

Comment: You can simply this in a few places. For example, there's already a built-in predicate that does what your `remove` does. Check out `select`. `check` isn't required if you can assume that all of your terms are of the form `X/N` where `N` is an integer. Or more generally, `N` can be any atom if you use `@<`, `@>`, etc, as your comparator in `larger`. Getting rid of `check` eliminates the `maplist` calls.